# How to limit using conditional with Ruby IMAP

Tags: ruby, imap

I'm a super-novice with Ruby, and playing around with the IMAP library. The below program seems to work but it goes on forever until all messages are loaded. How would I limit the output to an X number of messages, like if I only wanted to show 10? I imagine it's some sort of "if envelope ="  -- but don't know what to put there. Thanks!

```
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('mail.domain.com')
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', ' ', ' ')
imap.examine('INBOX')
imap.search(["SEEN"]).each do |message_id|
  envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
  puts "#{envelope.from[0].name}: \t#{envelope.subject}"
end
```

Not sure if appropriate here or if I should make a new question, but using the "SINCE" idea from below, how would I display a count of all the emails (elements in the array) fetched?

```
imap.examine('INBOX')
  imap.search(["SINCE", "17-Feb-2012"]).each do |message_id| 
  envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
  puts "#{envelope.from[0].name}: \t#{envelope.subject}"
   puts "#{envelope.count}"
  end
```

The above puts the number 10 after every line, regardless of the amount of emails returned. How would I a) only put the result at the end of all the emails listed and b) find a true count of the elements in the array?

OK, figured out the second part:

```
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('mail.domain.com')
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'username', 'password')
imap.examine('INBOX')
mail_count = imap.search(["SINCE", "20-Feb-2012"]) 
puts mail_count.count
```

Comment: search is just returning an array, so you could always just look at the first 10 elements rather than iterating over each...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice` to get only N results:

```
imap.search(["SEEN"]).slice(0, 10).each do |message_id|
  ...
end
```

The first parameter (here is 0) specified the start position, and the second the total number you need.

Note: based on IMAP's search method's implementation, the underlying calling might still fetch all messages from the server.

Comment: thanks! this worked and I don't think it fetched all messages, because it only took a few seconds. I've been trying to define a new variable message_count and += 1 but that seems to either do nothing or show me 10 copies of each message, depending on where I put it. This works perfectly though.

Comment: Yeah `search` returns an array of message ids (which might include ids from all messages) and it returns fast. Please mark this as best answer if it works as what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

`imap.search` sends a search command to the mailbox, gets back an array or message sequence numbers. The each block runs on all of them. You can also try limiting the number of results coming from search by specifying some limiting keys, like `SINCE` and `BEFORE`.

```
imap.search("BEFORE", "30-Jan-2012", "SINCE", "1-Jan-2012")
```

[link to documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-search).

Comment: posted a follow up Q based on your suggestion above